# How to bind a DataTrigger to a non-bound attribute?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

This is not in a template, it is a `<Label>` in the body of my XAML document. Notice that the Content of the label is set to 'PENDING'. This is monitoring a server connection and at various times the code-behind might change the value of the content to CONNECTED or ERROR.  When that happens, I would like for the color of the text to change.  I thought this would do it, but it doesn't... all I get is black text.

```
<Label x:Name="lbl_Connected" Content="PENDING" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Content.Value}"  Value="CONNECTED">
                    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Content.Value}" Value="PENDING">
                    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Content.Value}" Value="ERROR">
                    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Can someone tell me how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the ".Value" part from the Binding's Path, i.e.:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Content}" Value="CONNECTED">
    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Anyway if I were you, I would use a Binding in order to set the Label content and a [converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle the Foreground color.

Comment: I was so close!!  I only learned about DataTriggers earlier today! :)

Comment: I guess you will enjoy Learning WPF ;-)

Comment: Liking it better than WinForms for sure!